# How to check for first element in JavaScript that has no style of display none?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a list of li elements as I filter data I exclude the unneeded elements by setting the display to none. I would like to check for the first element that has no style of display set to it how can I do this:
Example of element with display none:

```
<li style="display: none;"><a href="#" data-key="81" data-value="Example 1">Data</a></li>
```

Example of element that has no attribute of display none:

```
<li style=""><a href="#" data-key="1" data-value="Example2">Example2</a></li>
```

My JavaScript Code:

```
var liValue = $("#UlId").find('li:not([style*="display: none"])').val();
```

How can I get the first li that is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want first visible value  `find` and `eq(0)` is your friend.

```js
var liValue = $("#UlId").find('li:not([style*="display: none"])').eq(0).find('a').text();
console.log(liValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="UlId">
  <li style="display: none;"><a href="#" data-key="81" data-value="Example 1">Data</a></li>
  <li style=""><a href="#" data-key="1" data-value="Example2">Example2</a></li>
  <li style=""><a href="#" data-key="2" data-value="Example3">Example3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
$('li:visible:first')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).